# Creating document from google sheets app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a document using google app scripts from a sheet. I have the following function

```
function createDoc() {

 DocumentApp.create('TEST_DOCUMENT');

}
```

But when I run it I get the error

`Exception: You do not have permission to call DocumentApp.create. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents (linje 26).`

In my google app scripts `appscript.json` I've added

```
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents"
],
```

For the necessary permissions. But I'm still getting the same error. Anyone know why?

EDIT:

**My createDoc() function (at the bottom)**

[image: My createDoc() func]

How I call the `createDoc() function`

[image]

**The error message**

[image]

**My appscript.json**
[image]

Comment: It's weird. I can't reproduce the error. Your code creates a new document with no problem. https://imgur.com/NXjs5Kr.png

Comment: Is it a custom function, btw? A custom function can't do it indeed.

Comment: @YuriKhristich Hm.. that is odd.

Comment: hm, it is a fucntion that i've created in my app script editor bound to a google sheet. That shouldn't work?

Comment: This is not reproducible on my side. Are you trying to execute that function from an [`onEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger? If yes, this is not feasible (check the [Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) ), you have to attach an [Installable Trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). If not, the script is new?

Comment: @YuriKhristich I added some pictures that hopefully clarify my situation more

Comment: From your screenshots I see that you're trying to run the script as a custom function https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions It doesn't work this way. A custom function cannot create files. They have many restrictions. "Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask users to authorize access to personal data. Consequently, they can only call services that do not have access to personal data, specifically the following:"

Comment: In your situation, is it required to run your script as the custom function? If you want it, I think that there is a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) it is not possible to use functions that require authorization. As explained in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services):

> Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask users to authorize access to personal data. Consequently, they can only call services that do not have access to personal data.

As a workaround I recommend you to add your function to a [Custom Menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#menus):

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .createMenu('Custom Menu')
    .addItem('Create new Doc', 'createDoc')
    .addToUi()
}
function createDoc(){
  DocumentApp.create(`My new Doc - ${new Date().toLocaleDateString()}`)
}
```